# Question about wording of Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Since I am not good at English, I am confused of what the following sentence means from T/F question.

*If T is linear map, then T carries linearly independent subsets of V onto linearly independent subsets of W*

I don't understand what carry onto means exactly. Does it mean that if T has independent subsets of V and there is a linearly independent subset of W? You don't have to give me the answer whether it is true or false because it is a homework.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I will rephrase the question in the usual symbolic notation of linear algebra.

"True or False: Let $V,W$ be vector spaces. If $T: V \to W$ is a linear transformation, then for any linearly independent subset $\{\vec{v}_1, \dots, \vec{v}_n\}$ in $V$, the set $\{T(\vec{v}_1), \dots , T(\vec{v}_{n}) \}$ is linearly independent in $W$."

---

**Note**: I am merely rephrasing what the true or false question is asking. I am not asserting that it is true or false. That is for you to decide :)

**Other Note:** The word "onto" is typically used in math (and particularly often in intro linear algebra courses in the US) to mean "surjective", but I don't think the author of this question intended that. If "onto" was intentionally used, and intended to mean surjective, I would interpret the question as asking if the linear transformation $T$ was a surjective function when restricted to the set of all linearly independent subsets of $V$, as a map to the set of all linearly independent subsets of $W$. This interpretation still makes mathematical sense as a true or false question, but I would be surprised if this was the intended interpretation.

Comment: Thank you so much!